# Remove "</div>" (and anything after it) from a string

Tags: vb.net

I would like to remove the substring `"</div>"` from a larger string. Since this does not necessarily appear at the end, any text appearing after this token should be removed as well. Since `Split` and `Remove` only allow integers, how would I do this?

For example, after making the changes
`"Wanted text</div> arbitrary text"` becomes `"Wanted text"`

Comment: `</div>` is six characters long, so `str.Substring(0, str.Length - 6)`. If this isn’t flexible enough, you’ll need to expand your question.

Comment: I must've worded it incorrectly. I meant remove from a sting, `"</div>"` to the end of that string.

Comment: Yes, that’s what that code snippet does.

Comment: `Wanted text</div> arbitrary text` I want to purge the unneeded text as well as the div tag.

Comment: If you worded incorrectly, why not edit the question and show an example of the input string, and the desired output, so it's clear? That helps people to answer the question appropriately. Remember, no one knows the context of your problem without you adding some more information for clarity,

Comment: It was originally correct in wording until minitech edited it. He must have assumed I made a mistake.

Comment: I think he edited it based on your title, which does seem to indicate you have a string with </div> at the end of it, which you want to remove. That's what I thought when I read the title, as well. Feel free to edit again and make your requirement clear. Edit: never mind, it says "to end from string". How about newStr = str.Replace("</div>", "") & "</div>". This assumes that you either only have one instance of </div> in your string, or you want to remove all of them if you have more than one. And adds just one at the end.

Comment: I down voted the question because it is very poorly worded and could really use some examples of input and desired output for clarity.

Comment: I down voted because there no relational understanding of the elements or methods being used in the scope of the question.

Comment: @David then you should have considered editing the question to make it clearer. Teach by example. New users will learn better how to ask questions if you can show them how.

Comment: OP, I upvoted your question back after the nice edit @nrbrooks just made :)

Comment: Sorry about the edit. “Remove `</div>` to the end of a string” is only almost valid English and the closest one was replacing that with “from” :P

Comment: @David Even if it takes a little extra effort to help a newer user, it pays off when they learn early on. I had just as much context you did, but by reading OP's comments (where an example was provided) I was able to edit and improve the question.

Comment: @nrbrooks - I still didn't trust that was the final need :) But I take your point in good consideration, and you're right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although your question appears to be "incomplete", reading through the comments it appears that you want to remove the closing DIV tag along with whatever text appears after it.

If that's the case, then this code should do the work:

```
Dim txt As String = "Wanted text</div> arbitrary text"
Dim p As Integer = txt.ToLower().IndexOf("</div>")
If p <> -1 Then txt = txt.Substring(0, p)
```

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm. As for the poor wording, sorry. I am quite tired.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `.Split()` without needing to check for the existence of `<div>` or getting the location.

```vb
Dim txt As String = "Wanted text</div> arbitrary text"
txt = txt.Split( New String() {"</div>"}, StringSplitOptions.None )(0)
```